# How does Lazy Loading work for compiled Ionic apps?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, lazy-loading, ionic4

I understand lazy loading's advantages in web... but is there any advantage to using it if my app is only going to be used compiled to Android and iOs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but is there any advantage to using it if my app is only going to be
>   used compiled to Android and iOS?

No difference. It behaves same like web app since Ionic uses webview at the end. You'll have all the benefits of lazy loading even with the native or compiled app. Such as huge performance boost on startup and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like Angular, Lazy Loading let dev load app modules only when user is required. Translated: Implementing lazy loading, your app is getting a significant boost performance. I recommend always to read Josh Morony articles [like this](https://www.joshmorony.com/what-does-lazy-loading-do-in-ionic/).

Comment: What I mean is... does lazy loading have an impact on a compiled app? I don't see how it would "translate" the loading... since the app is a package and all the code should already be downloaded to the phone.